# cordova camera copyFile error code 1000

Tags: android, android-camera, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I got an error code 1000, if i choose an image from my photo library with the cordova plugin cordova-plugin-file 3.0.0 (android). I dont know what error code 1000 meas.
If i take a new photo, all works fine.

Has anybody an idea?

```
function optionsForType(type) {
    var source;
    switch (type) {
      case 0:
        source = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
        break;
      case 1:
        source = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
        break;
    }
    return {
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType: source,
      allowEdit: false,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    };
  }

function saveMedia(type) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var options = optionsForType(type);

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageUrl) {
      var name = imageUrl.substr(imageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      var namePath = imageUrl.substr(0, imageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      var newName = makeid() + name;
      console.log(newName, cordova.file.dataDirectory);
      $cordovaFile.copyFile(namePath, name, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newName)
          .then(function() {
            deferred.resolve(newName);
          }, function(e) {
            // e is error code 1000 
            console.error(e);
            deferred.reject(e);
          });
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

### tl;dr:

The problem is: the camera plugin return URL like this `content://...` but the file plugin seems to manage only URL like this `file:///...`

Use this plugin to convert the `content://...` URL in `file:///...` URL:

https://github.com/hiddentao/cordova-plugin-filepath

### Long version:

The error code 1000 means `UNKNOWN_ERR` you can see it in:

```
/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/src/android/FileUtils.java (l.68)
```

This `UNKNOW_ERR` is used in l.585

```
[...]
} else if(e instanceof JSONException ) {
    callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION));
} else {
    e.printStackTrace();
    callbackContext.error(FileUtils.UNKNOWN_ERR);
}
```

Has you can see for this unknown error a stack trace is printed. To see the stack trace I use the android monitor. To do that go to your android sdk folder and launch the monitor like this:

```
$ ./tools/monitor
```

For me the monitor expose this particular stack trace:

```
10-28 20:34:28.645: W/System.err(8846): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/ from pid=8846, uid=10085 requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()
10-28 20:34:28.648: W/System.err(8846): at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
10-28 20:34:28.648: W/System.err(8846): at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
10-28 20:34:28.649: W/System.err(8846): at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
10-28 20:34:28.649: W/System.err(8846): at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:420)
10-28 20:34:28.649: W/System.err(8846): at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:478)
10-28 20:34:28.649: W/System.err(8846): at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:422)
10-28 20:34:28.649: W/System.err(8846): at org.apache.cordova.file.ContentFilesystem.openCursorForURL(ContentFilesystem.java:170)
10-28 20:34:28.649: W/System.err(8846): at org.apache.cordova.file.ContentFilesystem.getFileMetadataForLocalURL(ContentFilesystem.java:126)
10-28 20:34:28.650: W/System.err(8846): at org.apache.cordova.file.Filesystem.exists(Filesystem.java:130)
10-28 20:34:28.650: W/System.err(8846): at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(FileUtils.java:619)
10-28 20:34:28.650: W/System.err(8846): at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.access$400(FileUtils.java:51)
10-28 20:34:28.650: W/System.err(8846): at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils$14.run(FileUtils.java:378)
10-28 20:34:28.650: W/System.err(8846): at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils$25.run(FileUtils.java:561)
10-28 20:34:28.650: W/System.err(8846): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-28 20:34:28.650: W/System.err(8846): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-28 20:34:28.650: W/System.err(8846): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

After googling 'android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS + camera + plugin' or something like 'FILE_URI + camera + resolveLocalFileSystemURL' I figured out that the camera plugin return URL like this `content://...` but the file plugin seems to manage only URL like this `file:///...`

So until this bug is not fixed (if it's realy a bug, I'm not an expert...) you can use this plugin to convert the `content://...` URL in `file:///...`URL:

https://github.com/hiddentao/cordova-plugin-filepath